# Execute query using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to execute some SQL code, connected directly to my database, but I don't know how to execute the query.

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("DATABASE");
SqlConnection myConnection = connect;
connect.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adptador = new SqlDataAdapter(@"QUERY", connect);
DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
adptador.Fill(TABLE);
clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TITLE");
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LISTNAME");
clientContext.Load(list);
ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem item = list.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);

foreach (DataRow row in tabela.Rows)
{
    item["LastModifiedBy"] = row["LastModifiedBy"].ToString();
    item.Update();
    cm = new SqlCommand("SQL COMMAND");
    **EXECUTE CM**
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Did you not read the documentation?

Comment: You do realise that `ExecuteQuery` isn't for getting results. `ExecuteReader` is for getting results...

Comment: ExecuteQuery is for a connection to SharePoint!
I want to execute the sqlcommand in the variable cm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlCommand has ExecuteReader, for executing the command and returning a dataset, ExecuteScalar for returning a single value of a primitive type (int, string, etc.), or executeNonQuery for returning nothing.  You can also pass a command to a SqlDataAdapter, and use that to populate a DataTable object.

Please google SqlCommand and you will find LOTS of examples.

Comment: The command that i want to execute is a sqlcommand and the result of this command will be only visible on the DataBase !

Comment: OK, what I said still applies.  By "Visible on the database" means it writes some records (or does something else) to the DB, and returns nothing?  If true, then call ExecuteNonQuery(), which executes the procedure and returns no results from the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your query is and what you want, you can use one of the [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) `Execute*` methods: `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteReader`, etc.

Comment: This is more of a comment asking for clarification than an answer.

Comment: I want to Do a Update to my Database !

Comment: First of all, please read documentation and search for tutorials. Then give it a try and come back to SO with a **specific question**, if you need help or your code is not working as expected. You can find plenty examples on this just by googling it. If you just need to execute an update procedure you could use `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score -1):

SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader()

Comment: missing the using statement, or you could use finally dispose.